# What does the Ctrl+Shift+D shorcut do in VS Code on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

From time to time I accidentally hit Ctrl+Shift+D instead of Ctrl+D to duplicate selection (I guess a bad piece of muscle memory from those four weeks when I used Atom). This shortcut removes the contents of the editor and it takes some 4 Undo's to undo it. I can't seem to unbind this shortcut because I cannot find it in the user shorcut preferences. There is a default binding (below) but it seems like something else and overriding it in user shortcuts doesn't change anything.

```
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+d",          "command": "workbench.view.debug",
                                     "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.debug.enabled" },
```

I was going to open an issue but Github directed me to SO instead, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in vscode opens Run and Debug View.

[image]

Can be remapped using Keyboard shortcuts settings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

[image]

[image]

Or you can Remove keybinding

[image]